# Copolymerization regioselectivity

Tags: polymers

When undergoing copolymerization via free radical mechanism Buna-N forms a certain way.
[Actual product and possible products](https://ibb.co/NSq8gGS)

Can we predict which of the products will be formed based on the substituents? 
If so, how?